# Prove a tight bound on the runtime of the following algoirthm

Tags: analysis, algorithms, computer-science, programming

```
function myfunc(n):
    // n is a positive integer greater than or equal to 2
    i = 2;
    while (i <= n):
        i = i * i
    return;
```

We know that if we have $i = i * 2$ in the loop body, the runtime would be $log_2(n)$. What would be the runtime if we have $i = i * i$ in the body?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you computed a few of the values of $i$?  Did you see a pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the loop body is `i = i * 2`, we see that `i` grows like this:
$$
2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5, \ldots
$$
The general term is $a_k = 2^k$, and by taking the inverse function we see that the runtime is $O(\log_2 n)$.

---

Likewise, when the loop body is `i = i * i`, we see that `i` grows like this:
$$
2^1, 2^2, 2^4, 2^8, 2^{16}, \ldots
$$
The general term is $b_k = 2^{2^{k-1}}$, and by taking the inverse function we see that the runtime is $O(\log_2 \log_2 n)$.